# iOS how to store time when app goes background

Tags: ios

I want to have a feature for my app that user can put app into background, and when user relaunch it, app can check the current time and compared to the old time, say every 1 hour the app can trigger an auto-refresh.

My problem is I don't know how to save the time object when the app goes to background and read it when launching.

Any best practice for this? Thank in advance.

Comment: Read This https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

Comment: Thank you. I feel my case is simpler, since I just want to make the time persistance, so I can read the object no matter the app is in background or active. is this related to background job or just object persistance?

Comment: User put app into background , In this case you store the time value in back ground mode methods , because iOS application run in back gourd limited period ,

Comment: but where do I save the time value? The app goes to background, the value should be released?

Comment: You can store in nsuserdefaults

Comment: Thanks! I am reading the doc

Comment: Once read the document ..! app life cycle methods also.

Comment: Store the time value in nsuserdefault or in your local DB, when app enters in  the background. And when the app comes to foreground check the old time and current time, based on that refresh your app.

Comment: yes what ever nsuserdefault or  local DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSUserDefaults to save the time.

Use the app delegate methods:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    //When application is going into background
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"backgroundTime"];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //When application comes back from background state
    NSDate *prevDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"backgroundTime"];
    NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval interval = [currDate timeIntervalSinceDate:prevDate];

    if (interval / 3600.0 > 1.0) {
        //Refresh your application
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the comments helped me a lot, and you have the same answers.